# Unable to automate action plans using Salesforce flow

Tags: visual-workflow, automation

I am trying to automate action plans when an opportunity is created or updated with a specific stage value. The record types are defined, action plan templates are created and published, on debugging the flow there are no errors. The flow is getting completed with no errors. Cannot figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: Why do you believe something is wrong anyway? What makes you thing you are unable to automate action plans in the first place?

Comment: @Fahad Khan I have same requirement which you have mentioned. I have published the Action plan template, On opportunity stage change, In record trigger flow how should use the task which has created under action plan template? I am not able to understand one point here, Need to create a task on stage change, but how I am going to use tasks under action plan template ? dose flow provide any function ? I am getting the template but not able to use the tasks. Please guide.